# "Consecutive" irreducible polynomials

Tags: polynomials, ac.commutative-algebra

If $P\in {\mathbb Z}[X]$ is a polynomial of degree $2$, then
it is easy to see that for any integer $m$, at least one of the polynomials
$P-(m+1),P-(m+2),P-(m+3),P-(m+4)$ is irreducible in ${\mathbb Z}[X]$. I believe a much stronger
property holds, namely that for any degree $d\geq 2$ and length $l\geq 1$, there is a constant
$C(d,l)$ such that for any polynomial $P\in {\mathbb Z}[X]$ of degree $d$, in any interval $I=\lbrace m+1,m+2, \ldots ,m+C(d,l) \rbrace$ we may encounter a subinterval of length $l$, 
$I'=\lbrace m+j+1,m+j+2, \ldots ,m+j+l \rbrace$ with $j+l \leq C(d,l)$ such that
$P-a$ is irreducible in ${\mathbb Z}[X]$ for any $a\in I'$. Is that property already known to be true, and are bounds known for $C(d,l)$ ?

Comment: It sounds good to me.  Moreover, restricting P to powers of x, I suspect you will get a good approximation on C(d,l).  I also suspect that something similar fails for polynomials over the rationals, and just investigating whether C(d,l) exists for R an ordered ring (and some notion of measure that allows l to make sense) is an interesting problem.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.03.29

Comment: I assume you take $P$ of degree $d$?

Comment: @ Laurent : $P$ is of degree $d$ indeed. I corrected the OP, thanks.

Comment: $6x^2+7x,6x^2+7x+1$ and $6x^2+7x+2$ are all reducible. The correct statement is with four consecutive values of quadratic polynomials.

Comment: I'd like to know an answer to the simpler problem, whether there's $C(d)$ such that $P-a$ is irreducible for some $a$, $0\lt a\le C(d)$. 

Comment: This is starting to sound like another generalization on Jacobsthal's function.  Gerhard "I Should Switch Gears Soon" Paseman, 2011.03.29

Comment: @ Gerry : Your $C(d)$ is what I call $C(d,1)$.

Comment: @Ewan, yes, that's why I called it a simpler problem; I'd like an answer to the case $\ell=1$ of your problem. 

Comment: I do not see the point of the $m$ in the problem statement. Arbitrary polynomials of a certain degree already allow arbitrary constant term.