# Adjacent reducible polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

Let $P[X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_N]$ be a reducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_N]$ such that $P[X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_N] + 1$ is also reducible. What (if anything) can we say about $P$?

One example of such a $P$ is $P(x) = 4x^2 + 4x = 4x(x + 1)$. Notice that $P(x) + 1 = 4x^2 + 4x + 1 = (2x + 1)^2$. Can you show other examples of such reducible pairs? I'm especially interested in the multivariate case.

Comment: Loosely related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59956/consecutive-irreducible-polynomials

Answer (score 2):

Take any commutative ring $R$ and an element $A\in SL(2,R)$ such that no entry in $A$ is a unit in $R$. Taking determinant, we get $pq-rs=1$ with $p,q,r,s$ non-units. Thus, both $rs, rs+1$ are reducible. In particular, take $R$ to be a polynomial ring for examples as you desire.

As a specific example, take $p=xy=q, r=xy+1,s=xy-1$.

Comment: Nice example! But how do you find polynomials $p, q, r, s in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $pq - rs = 1$? Put another way, how do you generate a matrix $A \in SL(2, \mathbb{Z}[x])$?

Comment: I gave you a simple example in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But more generally, how do you generate many examples?

Comment: For the univariate case: let $p$ and $r$ be any pair of coprime polynomials, so $\gcd(p,r) = 1$, and apply the extended Euclidean algoritthm to find $u$ and $v$ such that $up + vr = \gcd(p,q) = 1$.  Now let $q = u$ and $s = -v$.

Comment: @Gautam For example, take $p,q$ positive degree polynomials. Then $pq+1)(pq-1)$ is reducible. But so is $(pq+1)(pq-1)+1=p^2q^2$. These are by no means all possibilities.