# Irreducibility measure of integer polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

**(Partial) Question in short:** Let $p$ be a monic integer polynomial of degree $n$. Is there a natural number $k$ with $0 \leq k \leq n$ such that $p+k$ is irreducible over the integers?

Longer version:

Let $p$ be a monic polynomial over the integers. Define the irreducibility measure $d(p)$ of $p$ as the smallest integer $k \geq 0$ such that $p+k$ is irreducible over the integers.
Define $M_n:=$ sup $\{ d(p) | deg(p)=n \}$ for $n \geq 2$. Here $deg(p)$ is the degree of $p$.

> Question: Is it true that $M_n \leq n$? (Answer no, by Joachim König). Is there a good bound for $M_n$ ?

The question is based on some small computer experiments.

edit: Sorry I forgot the condition that the polynomials are monic (I did all computer experiments with that assumption. The answer by Joachim König gives a counterexample in the non-monic case).

Comment: It is perhaps better to define $d(p)$ as the least natural integer such that $p+i,p+i+1,p+i+k$ contains an irreducible polynomial for all $i\in\mathbb Z$. (This makes the definition invariant under translations $x\longmapsto x+\tau$ which seems natural for integral polynomials).

Comment: What's the counterexample in the non monic case?

Comment: @RijulSaini It was posted by Joachim König that $6x^2+7x$ is a counterexample, but he remarked that for non-monic polynomials of degree 2 $d(p) \leq 3$.

Comment: Similar questions arise at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59956/consecutive-irreducible-polynomials See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149362/large-gaps-between-consecutive-irreducible-polynomials-with-small-heights

Comment: @Mare At least $M_n\ge n$ is clear for all $n$, due to the polynomial $p(x)=x\cdot (x+1)\cdots (x+n-1) + x$, which is also given in one of the questions linked by Gerry Myerson.

Comment: It becomes true if we replace being reducible to having an integer root, that easily follows from $p(a)-p(b)$ being divisible by $a-b$. In particular, this yields $d=2,d=3$ cases.

Comment: Do you know that $M_n$ is finite for every $n$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov At least it should be finite assuming Uniform Faltings (e.g. implied by Bombieri-Lang conjecture): the reducible values of $f(x)-t$ are parameterized by integral points on a bounded number of curves $C_i: g_i(t,Y)=0$ of bounded genus (when $\deg(f)$ is fixed). Some of those might be genus $\le 1$, but we can blow up the genus (while still keeping it bounded in terms of $\deg(f)$) by e.g. considering something like $g_i(t^2,Y)=0$ (i.e., care only about specialization at squares), and now only a bounded number of $t^2$ would give reducible specializations.

Comment: @JoachimKönig well, yes, but these curves are very specific, so I admit that this is easier. This is finite when all guys have a linear factor. What about quadratic factors? For algebraic integers we still have that $a-b$ divides $p(a)-p(b)$, looks like a strong restriction.

Comment: Have you seen "Is Every Polynomial with Integer Coefficients Near an Irreducible Polynomial?" by Michael Filaseta? It might be related.

Answer (score 7):

For $f=x^6 - 3x^5 - 2x^4 + 10x^3 + x^2 - 8x - 5$, one has
$$f=(x^3 - 2x^2 - 2x + 5)(x^3 - x^2 - 2x - 1),$$
$$f+1=(x-2)(x^5 - x^4 - 4x^3 + 2x^2 + 5x + 2),$$
$$f+2=(x^2-x-1)(x^4 - 2x^3 - 3x^2 + 5x + 3),$$
$$f+3=(x^2-2)(x^4 - 3x^3 + 4x + 1),$$
$$f+4=(x+1)(x^5 - 4x^4 + 2x^3 + 8x^2 - 7x - 1),$$
$$f+5=x(x^5 - 3x^4 - 2x^3 + 10x^2 + x - 8),$$
$$f+6=(x-1)(x^5 - 2x^4 - 4x^3 + 6x^2 + 7x - 1).$$

(Found more or less by brute force.)

PS: In order to not cause unnecessary confusion, the "answer" giving a counterexample for the ``non-monic case", currently mentioned in the OP, was $f(x)=6x^2+7x$; this was removed as a separate answer after the OP had been altered.

Comment: Thanks. I leave the question open a bit before I accept the answer since Im interested to see what $M_n$ might be for small $n$ or whether there is a good bound.

Comment: @Mare I don't think you can hope for a really good general bound here, since any bound would be an effective result on the least admissible value in Hilbert's irreducibility theorem (for the special case $F(x,t) = f(x)+t$), see e.g. http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa69/aa6937.pdf   (I could just about imagine $M_4=4$ or $M_5=5$ could be provable (in case true), since those translate to integer solutions to somewhat managable systems of equations given by certain resolvent polynomials.)

Comment: For any finite degree, in principle it's possible to enumerate the possible degrees of factors and for each such to set up a system of bilinear equations on their coefficients, so for small $n$ it's just a matter of a lot of computation.

Comment: @PeterTaylor But you will have more variables than equations (even after some w.l.o.g.'s), so the issue remains whether the system has integral solutions.